# Will a DNS record for the main domain impact my subdomain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, migration

I want to move all content from the main domain to a subdomain. Then I will connect the main domain to webflow. To make it work I will have to change the DNS.

Will the subdomain be affected by the change of DNS? Or subdomain will keep the old DNS?

For example I have:

- `www.abc.example/2018`
- `www.abc.example/2017`
- `www.abc.example/2016`
- `www.abc.example/2015`

All those I want to move to subdomain (`histoy.abc.example`)

Than on main domain `www.abc.example` I want to connect webflow. 
To do that I have to change A and `CNAME` of main domain.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you have a wildcard catch-all DNS record powering the subdomain, or does it its own normal `A`/`CNAME` record?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `A` or `ALIAS` record of a top-level domain will not change how the subdomains resolve.

You can serve whatever files you would like from a subdomain using an `A` or `CNAME` on that subdomain, and it will not affect the `A` or `ALIAS` record on your top-level domain.

Keep in mind that `www` *is* a subdomain. 99.9% of the time you will want it to resolve to the same target as the bare top-level domain, so keep that in mind.